# Issue with dual-NIC clients and netplan swapping ethernet interfaces

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, ethernet, netplan

Background: 1500+ stations running Ubuntu Server + `ubuntu-desktop-minimal`, most are still on 20.04, new stations are all deployed with 22.04 (with a `ubuntu-desktop-minimal --no-install-recommends` flag for 22.04). Users need to be able to interact with network settings GUI, so we use `NetworkManager`, set via `netplan`, to manage network settings.

We are running into an interesting issue with Ubuntu Server 22.04 where after running a `netplan` to set static IP/DHCP settings on the 2 NIC ports on the client, they will, after some number of reboots, "flip" where the MAC that was on `eth0` will show up as the MAC address for `eth1`. Physically swapping the cable to `eth1` will restore connection with the static IP assigned originally to `eth0`. After another reboot, the ports will flip back (requiring another cable change if that was swapped in the process as well). In our experience, the swap has not happened again.

We have 2 `netplan` playbooks we use in the process of preparing these systems:

1. `00-installer-config.yaml` - this is installed and applied during PXE install process, sets both interfaces to DHCP-enabled

> ```
> cat /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
> # This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
> network:
>   ethernets:
>     eth0:
>       dhcp-identifier: mac
>       dhcp4: true
>     eth1:
>       dhcp-identifier: mac
>       dhcp4: true
>   version: 2
> ```

2. `01-network-manager-all.yaml` - Playbook is run during the station provisioning process, shortly after imaging. We initially thought the problem "flip" started after running this playbook; further testing proves this is not the case.

> ```
> cat /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
> #BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
> network:
>   version: 2
>   renderer: NetworkManager
>   ethernets:
>     eth0:
>       dhcp4: no
>       addresses:
>         - 172.31.252.51/24
>       routes:
>         - to: default
>           via: 172.31.252.254
>       nameservers:
>         addresses: [172.16.103.251,172.16.103.252]
>     eth1:
>       dhcp4: no
> #END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
> ```

This is a significant issue for us, as anytime one of these systems is added/replaced, it is basically a ticking clock waiting for it to come back from a reboot with an unresponsive network.

Has anyone seen of, or even heard of, an error like this? I have a bunch more information, wanted to keep the top post reasonable, happy to provide additional details.

**Attempted remediations:**

- Updating kernel version to 6.0, 6.1, and 6.4 during PXE install process
- erased all services of `systemd-networkd` after imaging to force everything to `NetworkManager`
- Added `match` variable, with `name` and `driver` matching. netplan applied successfully, rebooted 5 times without issue, ports flipped on the 6th reboot.
- Getting closer. Matched on `macaddress` in the Ansible that creates the 01 `netplan` after imaging. Ports flipped after 4 reboots, but strangely retained connection, despite `ip addr` showing flipped IPs.

> ```
> - name: Copy network configuration in 01-network-manager-all.yaml   blockinfile:
>     path: /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
>     block: |
>       network:
>         version: 2
>         renderer: NetworkManager
>         ethernets:
>           eth0:
>             match:
>               macaddress: {{ansible_eth0.macaddress}}
>             dhcp4: no
>             addresses:
>               - {{ ansible_host }}/24
>             routes:
>               - to: default
>                 via: {{ ansible_host.split('.')[0:3] | join('.') }}.254
>             nameservers:
>               addresses: {{ default_dns }}
>           eth1:
>             match:
>               macaddress: {{ansible_eth1.macaddress}}
>             dhcp4: no
> ```

Resultant `netplan`:

> ```
> cat /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
> #BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
> network:
>   version: 2
>   renderer: NetworkManager
>   ethernets:
>     eth0:
>       match:
>         macaddress: c4:00:ad:87:be:20
>       dhcp4: no
>       addresses:
>         - 172.31.252.51/24
>       routes:
>         - to: default
>           via: 172.31.252.254
>       nameservers:
>         addresses: [172.16.103.251,172.16.103.252]
>     eth1:
>       match:
>         macaddress: c4:00:ad:87:be:1f
>       dhcp4: no
> #END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
> ```

Flipped ports (that still allow ssh to 172.31.252.51, no cable moves):

> ```
> 2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
>     link/ether c4:00:ad:87:be:1f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
>     altname enp0s31f6
> 3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
>     link/ether c4:00:ad:87:be:20 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
>     altname enp1s0
>     inet 172.31.252.51/24 brd 172.31.252.255 scope global noprefixroute eth1
>        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
> ```

Comment: Please [edit] with your netplan yaml. If you are matching on the name, stop doing that. Under some conditions, it's not guaranteed to be stable across reboots. You should match on the "Fixed MAC address" original value: https://netplan.readthedocs.io/en/stable/netplan-yaml/#properties-for-physical-device-types

Comment: You need to add a `match` section in your first netplan. You could use the `macaddress` and `ansible_interfaces` fact: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html . Then you would sort them in your playbook to get a consistent order. Exactly how I haven't tested

Comment: Thank you! I will dig in both comments today, much appreciated!

Comment: I said to match on the macaddress. The ports flipping is not an error, and it is by design

Comment: Ok, that looks like it works. If you don't sort `{{ansible_eth{0,1}.macaddress}}`, it might only work if you don't run Ansible twice on the same host. Are there any remaining problems? If not, you could post an answer

Comment: Testing this thoroughly before I post an answer, thank you for the assistance! Can you please explain/reference the port flipping happening not by error, but by design, and why that would've changed from 20.04?

Comment: It is by design that the loading is asynchronous. If you want consistency, you can enable the enpXsX or enx.... naming features. Basically Linux will number and load the ports in the order it finds them so startup is faster